# How to redirect user to the specific URL and display notice

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect users upon registration, login, or any operation, to a specific page.  If the user does something something like click "go back", the displayed notice should disappear.
What function would I use?

```
add_action('redirectToProfil', array( $this, 'redirectToProfile' )); 

public function redirectToProfile(){
    $url = get_site_url(null, '/profile');
    wp_safe_redirect( $url );
    exit;
}

do_action('redirectToProfil');
```

I tried using `$_GET` parameters, but it did not work for me.

**SOLUTION**

I use `$_SESSION[]`.

Comment: Is the notice once per session, e.g. you can check if you've shown it with a cookie, or only once ever? e.g. you can flag that the user has seen / accepted in user options

Comment: which function i must use to display notice?

Comment: How do you want to display the notice? Just as text on the page? As a separate page? As a modal light box on the page? Something else?

Comment: only text with <div>

Comment: And i want transfer some value with redirect action. Can help?